# 論文のPDFからグラフとそのグラフの説明文をセットで抜き出したい

Tags: python, pdf

タイトルのようなことをしてみたくて、方法を探したところ以下のようなやり方が見つかりました。https://github.com/allenai/pdffigures2
しかし、Scalaベースで書いてあり、できればPythonで動かせるプログラムがないか探しております。何かおすすめありましたら、教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

質問にあった Scala のプログラムを Python から呼び出すプログラムが公開されています。
それ自身が論文のための実験コードで、実用ではないと書いてありますが、参考になるかもしれません。

[allenai/deepfigures-open](https://github.com/allenai/deepfigures-open)

他はセットで抜き出せるかは不明ですが、PDFminerとPyPDF2あたりが有名そうな感じです。

- PDFminer
  [PythonでPDFからテキストを抽出する方法](https://webbigdata.jp/bigdata/post-272) / [PythonでPDFからjpeg画像を抽出する方法](https://webbigdata.jp/bigdata/post-825)
  [【PDFMiner】PDFからテキストの抽出](https://qiita.com/mczkzk/items/894110558fb890c930b5) / [PDFからテキストデータをうまく抜けるかの検証結果のご報告（pdfminer.six)／Python](https://arakan-pgm-ai.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/01/07/080000)
- PyPDF2
  [pythonでPDFから画像の抽出する備忘録](https://note.mu/pintcloud/n/nd09c5b8fe615)
  [Extracting PDF Metadata and Text With Python](https://dzone.com/articles/extracting-pdf-metadata-and-text-with-python)
  [How to robustly extract author names from pdf papers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50575957/9014308)

---

Pythonによるツールの特集記事です。
[Working with PDFs in Python: Reading and Splitting Pages](https://stackabuse.com/working-with-pdfs-in-python-reading-and-splitting-pages/)

Pythonに限らず、色々なツールが紹介されているQ&A記事がありました。
[Extracting information from PDFs of research papers closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1813427/9014308)

Cで書いたツールの集合とかもあります。
[XpdfReader](http://www.xpdfreader.com/index.html)

Comment: 他のやり方でやってみたところ、うまくいきました。ありがとうございます。